# Introductory Abstract Algebra book for self study with solution manual

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have covered basics of proofs and i am doing Real Analysis side by side and so i wanted to dive into abstract algebra. Please suggest me for the same

I would like to have a textbook in similar to taste of "***Understanding Analysis***" by Stephen Abbot. Basically a book that teaches intuition behind the subject

Thanks

Comment: I mean to say that i have started real analysis by self study on my own. I am not having heavy background i mean to say as i am self taught but going good with real analysis though from book " Understanding alanlsysi "

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for your encouragement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*. The solution to each odd numbered exercise is in the back.

Comment: i tried it but i didnot like second chapter on dihedrals. too little info on digedrals and questions in exercise were not approrpiate for that info

Comment: Is there anything else you've omitted from the body of the question? Because we can't read minds.

Comment: nothing else,,,,

Answer (score 3):

1. Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote
2. Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian
3. Basic Abstract Algebra by Bhattacharya, Jain and Nagpaul
4. A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra by W W Sawyer